# JavaFX ScatterChart: How to set icon for data points?

Tags: java, javafx

I am using JavaFX to create a ScatterChart. I want to change the default symbols for the data points to my own icons, which are png images. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the node of each of your data items to a (different) ImageView.

[`javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data<X,Y>.setNode(node)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#setNode-javafx.scene.Node-)

Answer (score -1):

To change the app icon, there is a **getIcons** method in **Stage** object

```
getIcons().add(new Image("icon.png"));
```